# How to determine the current cache size for Apollo client's InMemoryCache

Tags: apollo-client

I need to do some memory usage profiling for a react native app using Apollo Client. Is there an easy way to determine how big the cache has grown at a certain point in time (API call or any other way of determining the size of the InMemoryCache)?

Comment: Did you end up finding a way?

Comment: I am also interested in learning more about this.